# Could humans be able to create a modern society in a water planet?

Tags: alternate-worlds

If the world we live in is a water planet, or a planet with little land, would humanity be able to survive and if they could, can they reach the type of civilization or society we have. Like able to create buildings or cities on water (that might be a stretch of what they could but just a theory)

Comment: You need more information about your planet. For example, is it the same as Earth, just with more water? Or is it some other type of planet with different composition and biosphere? It will affect the resources available to survive. If it is like Earth, there are civilizations that have colonized islands or shallow lakes and basins...

Comment: Related and for your interest: [Plant used to create genetically-engineered floating-islands.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199623/plant-used-to-create-genetically-engineered-floating-islands). There's a load of [related questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=floating+islands) for your perusal. Then there's the [underwater-habitat questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=underwater+habitat).

Comment: Then there's the [Self-sufficient ark](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8368/self-sufficient-ark) and the [What's the weather like on a waterworld](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/198235/what-would-the-weather-or-environment-be-like-on-a-mostly-water-covered-world) - it's really well worthwhile making use of the search facility to get some great ideas as to what might be possible.

Comment: VTC: What is the purpose of this Q? Earth has obvious Oceania civilizations that prove humanity can survive and thrive in a water world. But worse, there isn't a problem here to solve (c.f. [help/dont-ask], "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where there is no actual problem to be solved.") If you want them to survive, choose that and move on. If you don't, choose that and move on.

Answer (score 0):

The Pacific Island societies managed it. They didn't get to our level, but were empire building at the time of European contact.

The main blocking point for them was being mostly volcanic Islands the natural resources for metal working etc, were absent. But there's no reason your people couldn't manage it if the raw materials exist. It's just a spark of genius from a single person that gets tech started in a new way. Polynesians were highly advanced in many ways, well beyond the Europeans.

Comment: +1 and DRAT! I was working on a very similar answer, but you posted before me. I sould be more concise. Basic civilizatation needs wood, rope, and some method of passing down info (optimally writing, but oral tradition and other methods may suffice). It all comes down to access to metalworking if you want to start down the road to modern.

Comment: @EscapedLunatic yeah, raw materials for metal working and it's good to go. Polynesians were stuck in the stone age without it, but pretty advanced in other areas.

Comment: A world with no land and water at least 100 meters deep everywhere would be interesting. You can't even have a stone age until you figure out how to acquire stones. I think Polynesians would still be able to build an impressive culture in an environment like this despite these material disadvantages.

Comment: @EscapedLunatic na they'd drown